# Xml schema how to be?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a simple xml and im trying to make an xml-schema of this xml

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<drink>
    <id>0001</id>
    <name>krasi</name>
    <producer>someone</producer>
    <price>12.50</price>
    <category>red_wine</category>
    <img   src="images/red_wine.jpg" width="25" height="80"  /> 
</drink>
```

the root tag is 'drink' and the xml has only one product inside

i try to make the xml schema and keep the xml like this!
And what i need to add to my xml for validation against the xml-schema?

Comment: Looks to me as if you haven't made any serious attempt to solve this yourself before asking the question. Stackoverflow isn't intended to be a substitute for reading and learning.

Comment: sorry....its not that i use stackoverflow as substitute....i write bellow that i solved it exept the img...right now i solved the img too....i am new in xml and xsd too..so its hard for me to find out whats going on with those two ..ty anyway...your advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

xml schema something like...

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="drink">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="producer" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element name="category" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```